# Identify classical instrument in "Code Geass" Anime episode

Tags: replication

What instrument is used at 18:44 in Code Geass, Episode 5?

[Video link](http://www.watchcartoononline.com/code-geass-episode-5-english-dubbed) | [Extracted audio link](https://clyp.it/ee0wlrji)

I want to find samples of it or reproduce it via synth.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The link is dead, so it isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: I just tried and the link worked fine for me. i'll try and find a different link.

Comment: That is a hapsichord: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71iUAFFQ8ik

Answer (score 1):

The instrument is most likely a [Harpsichord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harpsichord).

You can find [Attribution 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) licensed samples in the [Peiman Khosravi samples](https://archive.org/details/PeimanKhosravi) and [OpenPathMusic samples v4](https://archive.org/details/OpenPathMusic44V4) sound collections.

There is a [free to use](http://sonimusicae.free.fr/blanchet-Licence-en.html) Harpsichord soundbank (sf2 & Kontakt 2) available from [Soni Musicae](http://sonimusicae.free.fr/blanchet1-en.html).